# On NetBeans(JAVA), Sound file suddenly stops playing when I start/test my program

Tags: java, netbeans, playing

First of all, this is a odd problem that im trying to fix since I got netbeans and started programming. Basically: I made a simple program with a music that should be playing while the program is running, but when the music just starts playing, it will last only some seconds because it suddenly stops playing with no apparent reason. I just open the program and click the button that makes the music to iniciate, and then it suddenly stops with 3 or 4 seconds(this is random, sometimes it ll last longer).

THE CURIOUS THING IS: On my notebook, if I try to test the program while in netbeans yet, the problem always occurs, BUT if I build the program, the problem goes away.

In other hand, if I test or build the same program on my pc(high-end), that problem will occur while testing on netbeans and after building it too, so no way to get ridding off it on pc, only on my notebook after building it(if I just test it while on netbeans without building, the problem will occur).That happens with every sound file or music that I try, also all of them are on wav format. Im not sure but I have installed K-lite mega codec pack on both systems, but dunno if its causing that. Here is part of my program where the sound file is started(and my importations):

```
//importations below
import java.applet.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
```

---

```
//my program sound stuff below

   File file = new File("C:\\Users\\MY-PC\\Desktop\\Projetos\\src\\javaapplication9\\cave of the past.wav");
       AudioClip clip=null;
       try{
       clip = Applet.newAudioClip(file.toURI().toURL());
       }
       catch(MalformedURLException lol){
           System.err.println("LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOL");
       }
        clip.loop();
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found a way that works as I want:

```
AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("C:/Folder/musicfile.wav").getAbsoluteFile());
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioInputStream);
        clip.start();
```